# How to bootstrap Guice Injector within Quarkus？

Tags: guice, mybatis, quarkus

for my project I use Mybatis as persistance layer . Considering Quarkus Arc (CDI) may not be quite stable, I'm trying to use Guice as DI tool within quarkus. I'm using [MyBatis-Guice](http://mybatis.org/guice/index.html). But from quarkus doc, I only see [startup event](https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle) as application initialization and seems custom main-method is not supported as entry point by Quarkus. (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/284 ; https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5291)

Any advice on how to bootstrap Guice Injector within quarkus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Considering Quarkus Arc (CDI) may not be quite stable

This statement is totally untrue. ArC is totally stable and at the core of Quarkus. If it wasn't stable, well, Quarkus wouldn't work at all as ArC is used everywhere inside the framework.

ArC has been specifically designed for Quarkus, build time injection and GraalVM so you should really use that one instead of trying to shoe in another injection framework - which probably won't work very well, and in any case, won't be as optimized as ArC for the Quarkus architecture.

And if, by any chance, you encounter any bug with ArC, just open a GitHub issue and things will get fixed quickly.

Comment: I dont mean to offense, but how does ArC work with MyBatis-CDI? The reason I turn to Guice is that I considered MyBatis-Guice would be more mature than MyBatis-CDI. I've tried  running examples from MyBatis in quarkus and always got  javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException ...Unsatisfied dependency for type .... , which is so frustrating.  Do you have any examples or code snippets for quarkus with MyBatis?

Comment: It's hard to help you without having the details. Create a simple reproducer and create a GitHub issue with it attached and the exception you get, we will have a look. In any case, having things working with ArC is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Hi Guillaume,  I post a related issue on [Github](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6490). Hope you could take a look. Thanks a lot!